# Test Subscription multiple times

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-subscription, play-billing-library

I have a subscription with a free trial period and a reduced price period.
According to the Developers site (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#testing-renewals) there is some waiting time when testing a subscription.

I'm using the lates billing library
`com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.3`

I did the initial test with no issues, but now if I want to test the subscription again (with the same account), I don't get the free trial/reduce price option, just the regular subscription price.

Is there any way to reset the subscription (for testing only), so I can test the entire flow more than once?

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to research on this topic as well but didn't find any alternatives so far. The only this is to create different google account every time. At some point, you won't be able to create accounts anymore from desktop. Try creating accounts from a mobile device at some point you will be asked to verify account with a phone number and you can use a phone number just for several accounts. Then you need to get new sim cards.

Comment: It's mind blowing how Google hasn't provided a way to reset this.  Have you found a solution to this?